# MariaDB docker accessing from host Windows 10 vs Linux

Tags: docker, mariadb

It turned out that the cause for the problem on Docker/Windows asked below, is a local network problem with the Hyper-V on my side. So it has neither to do with a difference between Docker on Windows and Linux, nor is there any relation to MariaDB. I wanted to delete the question but was discouraged to do so because it already got answers.

---

I am new to docker but not to MySQL. I want to play with MariaDB in Docker. I created Docker installations both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

For the MariaDB container, I followed the description here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/ as it seemed to be more accurate than this: https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb.

I created a MariaDB Container using:

```
docker run --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -d mariadb:latest
```

"latest" pulled MariaDB server 10.5.8.

I verified that tcp access via port 3306 is enabled in my.cnf

```
[client-server]
port=3306
```

Running the MySQL client from inside the container works

```
docker exec -it MariaDB MySQL -u root -p
```

Running the MySQL client from the host

```
mysql -h 172.17.0.2 -u root -p
```

works on my Ubuntu host but not on my Windows 10 host. On Windows, the command returns after a while without any message.

Can you tell me why and help me?

Comment: I think I'm facing a network problem here on my office PC. From https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/ I learned that on Windows I must use the -p port mapping. I tried that already without success. 
Now I set up Docker and the MariaDB container on another PC (my home PC), and it worked immediately.
I think I should probably delete the question and create a new more generic network question with no relation to MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update your command to run mysql inside docker in Ubuntu system:

```
docker run --name mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -d mariadb:latest --port 3306:3306
```

#### Check your IPv4 address for WSL Network adapter in the Windows and Linux

Open powershell and execute the `ifconfig` command, then find WSL network adapter:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e96c:c3d6:464e:2a3b%72
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.240.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Your Windows IP is `172.20.240.1`

Now figure out the Linux Host IP with the `ip a` command and see IP in the same network as Windows:

```
5: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:ce:28:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.252.177/20 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fece:288e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

#### Connect from windows to linux server

`mysql -u root -h 172.20.252.177 -P 3306 -p`

#### Docker on linux vs Windows

On Linux docker is working in native way in your system. There is no official docker release for Windows. It means you need to emulate linux machine in Windows(and MacOS as well) and run there docker daemon.

When you emulate linux, the hypervisor creates new network to your emulated system, so docker is not running on localhost.

The main difference for you as a user is, that you cannot access applications running in docker like the localhost because it is running in VM, which has its own network IP.

Another difference are resources availability.
In linux docker deamon has access to all your resources(CPU, Memory, HDD, Networking etc). Of course you can create quotas for it, but it is not concern at the moment.

In Windows you ran VM and assign some limited resources to the emulated Linux. For example 20 GB Hdd, 1vCPU and 2GB of Ram. It is important in case of performance of your applications. They will be slower (if more resources is required) in windows than in Linux.

However When I work on Windows. I like it because i can create snapshot of docker VM and I can copy it to another computer. This is amazing, because you do not need to configure system when you install it or changing computer.

Comment: My question was not about accessing the MariaDB on Docker/Ubuntu from a Windows machine. It was about comparing the host access for both installations. Actually, I want to work with Docker on Windows, but here the host access doesn't work for me as described in the tutorials. On Ubuntu Docker, on the other hand, it worked immediately.

Comment: I have updated main differences. There is not to much differences. Main diff is, that there is no Docker for Windows. You can use it in windows, but actually it is running on Linux VM.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I don't know what to do with this question or whether I should better delete it. My problem cause is a local network issue, and not of general interest unless I would focus my question on this network issue. Suggestion?